# Axios post with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, google-cloud-functions

I have a basic firebase cloud function. I want to post a request with Axios (send Slack message). But the server returns "Error: could not handle the request (500)". Where is the problem? I use cors.

```
const cors = require('cors') 
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const Axios = require('axios')

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors()(request, response, () => {
    return Axios.post(
      `https://hooks.slack.com/services/*XXXXXXXXXXXXX*`,
      {
        blocks: [
          {
            type: 'section',
            text: {
              type: 'mrkdwn',
              text: 'hello',
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: I use Firebase free plan, but I use Node 8 as a dependency, which should work with this free plan till next year.

Comment: Please edit the question to show any errors you see in the functions console.  Without that, we have to guess what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using `cors` incorrectly. Also you should return any value using provided `response`. Check below for detail.

```js
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors(request, response, async () => {
    try {
      const res = await Axios.post(
        `https://hooks.slack.com/services/*XXXXXXXXXXXXX*`,
        {
          blocks: [
            {
              type: 'section',
              text: {
                type: 'mrkdwn',
                text: 'hello',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      );
      response.status(res.status).json(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(400).json(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Normally it would work but now I got an error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN hooks.slack.com:443, probably because Google does not allow you to do Outbound networking (other than Google services) when you are using their Spark plan.

Answer (score 1):

The way to accomplish this is to add the header *"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"* to the post. You would do it like this with the code you provided:

```js
const cors = require('cors') 
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const Axios = require('axios')

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors()(request, response, () => {
    return Axios.post(
      `https://hooks.slack.com/services/*XXXXXXXXXXXXX*`,
      {
        blocks: [
          {
            type: 'section',
            text: {
              type: 'mrkdwn',
              text: 'hello',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Slack API doesn't seem to play nice with regular JSON, which is the default of Axios, so that is why it needs to be changed.

Hope this fixes it for you!